# Updating a JSON field replaces whole document?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

In sql server 2016 I am expecting a document to have 3000+ fields in a JSON column. Can I update one field in the document without replacing to whole document. How can I do this?

Comment: Looks like you are in need of `document structured Database` like `MongoDB` rather a relation database like `SQL Server`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`JSON_MODIFY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921892.aspx) function:

> Updates the value of a property in a JSON string and returns the
>   updated JSON string.
>
> ```
> JSON_MODIFY ( expression , path , newValue )
> ```

Something like:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET json_column = JSON_MODIFY(json_column, '$.name', 'new_name')
WHERE id = 1;
```